# How do match and extract groups from regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a program where I am taking in input from a user.

I want to be able to detect when the user says something like:

"Set HP 25 to 9999"

and then extract both the 25 and 9999 using regex.

Is it:

```
if re.match(r"^Set HP ([\d]+) to ([\d]+)$", userstring)
```

and if so, how do I extract the two numbers the user entered also using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `matchobj.groups`

```
m = re.match(r"^Set HP (\d+) to (\d+)$", userstring)
if m:
    print m.groups()
```

Example:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"^Set HP (\d+) to (\d+)$", "Set HP 25 to 9999")
>>> if m:
    print m.groups()


('25', '9999')
>>>
```

Comment: it's unnecessary to use brackets interms of single item... For more than one, you must use them..

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `re.findall`

```
>>> s = "Set HP 25 to 9999"
>>> re.findall('\d+', s)
['25', '9999']
```

or extract the groups manually:

```
>>> match = re.match(r"^Set HP (\d+) to (\d+)$", s)
>>> match.group(1)
'25'
>>> match.group(2)
'9999'
```

note that `match.groups()` will give you all groups as a tuple:

```
>>> match.groups()
('25', '9999')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the numbers iteratively like:

```
for m in re.finditer(r"\d+",userstring):
   print m.group()
```

Comment: `filter(str.isdigit, userstring.split())`